# Identifying Views in the Visual Studio Tab List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, ide

In MVC you are likely to have many views with the same name (such as `Index.cshtml` or `Edit.aspx`) for the various controllers.

Depending on your working style, you might end up with a few tabs open in Visual Studio ending up with a tablist that looks like:

```
Index.cshtml|Index.cshtml|SomeController.cs|Edit.cshtml|Index.cshtml|Edit.cshtml|
```

It is possible to hover over the tabs and wait for the context hint to show up, but I was wondering if anyone had a technique or plugin where the correct file could be more easily identified at a glance (i.e. the `Index.cshtml` for the `SomeController`)?

Comment: Tools/Options/Projects & Solutions/General there is a 'Track Active Item' option, it only lets you see what the file is when it's the active file (in the editor) so maybe not quite what you want.

Comment: @K.Bob: That is okay for the current file, but I really want to be able to find the one I need without having to reselect it from the solution explorer (which can involve quite a few clicks, especially if areas are used).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be an extension in the [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) that will make your life easier. The [Document Well 2010 Plus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx) allows you to configure the document tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://www.tabsstudio.com/ may have the behavior you are looking for.

When you install it you should open the 'Tabs Studio Add-in Manager' and check 'Disambiguator'.

When you have different files open with the same name, it will display it's containing folder.

```
Home/Index.html | About/Index.html
```

Comment: Worth noting that *this addon costs $49*. Does look like it has the requested feature though, you own a copy of TabsStudio? May do the trial to check it out.

Comment: I known someone who has a copy of TabsStudio and uses it. I only tried the trial to check if it really covered your needs :-)

Comment: I downloaded the trial and verified this works as promised. However, I personally *dislike the addon very much*, amongst others because it's *mutually exclusive with the tab well plus* from power productivity tools. But even though I don't like the solution, the answer's still eligible for the bounty - given there are no other answers it shall be yours. Thanks again for taking the time to answer!